# Retrieving records with inner joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

My assignment is to get the the First name, Middle name and Last name for all Customers that have had an order before '2012-09-30' and after '2013-09-30'. I'm using the AdventureWorks2017 as a sample DB

Table: Sales.SalesOrderHeader

```
[SalesOrderID]
      ,[RevisionNumber]
      ,[OrderDate]
      ,[DueDate]
      ,[ShipDate]
      ,[Status]
      ,[OnlineOrderFlag]
      ,[SalesOrderNumber]
      ,[PurchaseOrderNumber]
      ,[AccountNumber]
      ,[CustomerID]
      ,[SalesPersonID]
      ,[TerritoryID]
      ,[BillToAddressID]
      ,[ShipToAddressID]
      ,[ShipMethodID]
      ,[CreditCardID]
      ,[CreditCardApprovalCode]
      ,[CurrencyRateID]
      ,[SubTotal]
      ,[TaxAmt]
      ,[Freight]
      ,[TotalDue]
      ,[Comment]
      ,[rowguid]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
```

Table: Person.Person

```
[BusinessEntityID]
      ,[PersonType]
      ,[NameStyle]
      ,[Title]
      ,[FirstName]
      ,[MiddleName]
      ,[LastName]
      ,[Suffix]
      ,[EmailPromotion]
      ,[AdditionalContactInfo]
      ,[Demographics]
      ,[rowguid]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
```

Table: Sales.Customers

```
[CustomerID]
      ,[PersonID]
      ,[StoreID]
      ,[TerritoryID]
      ,[AccountNumber]
      ,[rowguid]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
```

**My Query**

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_table.FirstName, 
    person_table.MiddleName, 
    person_table.LastName
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as sales_order_table
inner join Sales.Customer as sales_customer_table
on (sales_customer_table.CustomerID = sales_order_table.CustomerID
    and sales_order_table.OrderDate <= '2012-09-30' )
inner join Sales.Customer as sales_customer_table2
on (sales_customer_table2.CustomerID = sales_order_table.CustomerID
    and sales_order_table.OrderDate >= '2013-06-30' )
inner join Sales.Customer as match_result
on (match_result.CustomerID = sales_customer_table2.CustomerID)
inner join Person.Person as person_table
on (person_table.BusinessEntityID = match_result.PersonID)
```

In this current state returns no rows and im unsure where the problem is

**[UPDATE]**

Found a relatevly good solution to the problem by editing Bilal Fakih answer

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_table.FirstName,
  person_table.MiddleName, 
  person_table.LastName,
  count(*) as Total_Instanses
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as sales_order_table
inner join Sales.Customer as sales_customer_table
  on (sales_customer_table.CustomerID = sales_order_table.CustomerID)
inner join Person.Person as person_table
  on (person_table.BusinessEntityID = sales_customer_table.PersonID)
WHERE sales_order_table.OrderDate NOT BETWEEN '2012-09-30' AND '2013-06-30'
GROUP BY person_table.FirstName,
  person_table.MiddleName, 
  person_table.LastName
HAVING count(*) >= 2
```

The suggestion was good but it woud return records that only had one instance. Im running into a few corner cases now. For example If a person has made 2 Orders that are bewfore 2012 or after 2013 will still be shown. The result im looking for is for a person to show up only when he has made orders before AND after the given dates

Comment: Schematically: `SELECT person FROM sales JOIN persons JOIN customers GROUP BY person HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN date < '2012-09-30' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND COUNT(CASE WHEN date > '2013-09-30' THEN 1 END) > 0`

Comment: Consider using a `FROM` clause with only `Person.Person` and a  `WHERE` clause with `EXISTS` correlated subqueries. That will avoid the need for `DISTINCT` too.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I'm not sure if it works I don't have the dataset to test, but it should

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_table.FirstName, 
  person_table.MiddleName, 
  person_table.LastName
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as sales_order_table
inner join Sales.Customer as sales_customer_table
  on (sales_customer_table.CustomerID = sales_order_table.CustomerID
inner join Person.Person as person_table
  on (person_table.BusinessEntityID = match_result.PersonID)
WHERE sales_order_table.OrderDate NOT BETWEEN '2012-09-30' AND '2013-06-30'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply this using below. Also your dates filter was not correct.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.FirstName, 
            p.MiddleName, 
            p.LastName
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader as s
INNER JOIN Sales.Customer as c                 
ON c.CustomerID = s.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Person.Person as p
ON p.BusinessEntityID = c.PersonID)
WHERE s.OrderDate >= '2012-09-30'     <----- add this
AND s.OrderDate <= '2013-06-30' )     ---- and this
```

Answer (score 0):

> My assignment is to get the the First name, Middle name and Last name for all Customers that have had an order before '2012-09-30' and after '2013-09-30'.

One method uses aggregation:

```
SELECT p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName
FROM person_table p JOIN
     Sales.Customer c
     ON p.BusinessEntityID = c.PersonID JOIN
     Sales.SalesOrderHeader so
     ON c.CustomerID = so.Cus tomerID
GROUP BY p.FirstName, p.MiddleName, p.LastName
HAVING MIN(so.OrderDate) < '2020-09-30' AND
       MAX(so.OrderDate) >'2013-06-30';
```

I will say that this condition looks suspicious:

```
ON p.BusinessEntityID = c.PersonID
```

However, that is what you use in your query.  I would expect the person table to have an id called something like `PersonId`.

Comment: Weirdly not for, It's BusinessEntityID